# How to dump specific process to RAM file

Tags: dump

I use DumpIt tool to dump RAM to raw file for forensic job. But it have a problem that, sometime I just want to dump specific process like cmd or notepad but not dump all current process.

[my Dumpit program I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyvGY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sysinternals ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump). It can take dumps manually or by condition (like high CPU usage or unhandled exception).
Also you can take a dump using Process manager (but need to be careful and use 32-bit process manager if your target process is 32 bit as well)